# BlackBerry OS 7.1 file/database file in use

Tags: blackberry

If I run my app on BlackBerry OS 7.1, sometimes I exit and relaunch the app, I can not open/write the files that I opened the last time. But everything is fine in OS 6-.

Is there anyone meet the same problem? Or is it the bug of OS 7.1?

Answer (score 1):

To exit from your application always use `System.exit()` call.

It must free all taken resources. If it does not, then it is a RIM OS bug.

Comment: Wasn't able to find on forum complaints about file system error when db wasn't closed properly. But I'm not sure if it was with complete exit from application. Anyway author of question will figure out it himself soon. Removed previous comment